# xcode 4.4.1 c++11 headers still filed under tr1 ?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, include-path

I created a standard c++ library project and I tried to include `<tuple>` but it doesn't seem to be included as a top level header, instead I still need to include `<tr1/tuple>`. The llvm compiler dialect is set to `-std=c++11`.

Am I correct in assuming that even though xcode 4.4 has a c++11 compliant compiler it doesn't ship with a C++11 compliant standard library yet ?

This question might be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345271/xcode-4-3-and-c11-include-paths).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library selection configuration settings is independent of the compiler dialect, and is not found under the "basic" view of the project configuration (unless you edit it). Specifically the setting is called "C++ Standard Library" and you can find it in the "all" view.

I suspect you were expecting this to appear with (or be part of) the compiler dialect setting.

Comment: yah I kept looking in the configuration for other stuff, and by chance I found the setting for library selection.