# XCode std::thread C++

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading

For a small project for school I need to create a simple client / server construction which will run on a router (with openWRT) and I am trying to do something with threads in this application.

My C++ skills are very limited, so I found this on the [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c) as an basic example.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void doSomeWork( void )
{
    std::cout << "hello from thread..." << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::thread t( doSomeWork );
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this in Xcode (4.5.2) I get the following error:

> Attempt to use an deleted function

And it shows some code of:

```
__threaad_execute(tuple<_Fp, _Args...>& __t, __tuple_indices<_Indices...>)
{
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
}
```

I think I need to do something with 'build settings' or 'link library' or something? But I am not quite sure what to do exactly. I thought I might need to set the following settings [(which i found here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13621792/393548)

- In the Build Settings tab for your project, scroll down to "Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1 - Language"
- Set the setting "C++ Language Dialect" to "C++11 [-std=c++11]"
- Set the setting "C++ Standard Library" to "libc++ (LLVM standard C++ library with C++11 support)"

But those settings where already set.

Is there any flag / library or something I am missing?

Comment: You think you'll be getting the C++ STD on an embedded platform? Think again.

Comment: I don't know, OpenWRT is a linux based system. So I guess it will be there?

Comment: Well, there will almost definatly be a C STD, but the C++ one might be a little intensive for a router. If you need threads and C++ isn't working, go for Linux's `pthread`. Also, why are you developing for Linux in Xcode on LLVM? You need GCC and some cross compiling.

Comment: The coding will be done in Xcode, the actual compiling will be done through cross-compiling indeed. I'll have a look at pthread.

Comment: check out http://tinythreadpp.bitsnbites.eu/ it is a drop in replacement for c++11 threads.

Answer (score 2):

Use G++ instead of LLVM in XCode. Don't forget to link thread libs (-lpthread - or -pthread, -lrt) in compiler build settings. And count with the differences of thread behaviour across Win/Mac/Linux OS (despite it's POSIX)