# std::thread on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, stl, pthreads

Do all implementations of `std::thread` for iOS internally include `<pthread.h>`?

I know that some while ago, [this only worked with g++ and **-lpthread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16793346/192373), but many upgrades have arrived since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is positive. At least in Version 7.2 (7C68) of Xcode, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread` has unconditional

```
#include <pthread.h>
```