# Where is definition of std::function in clang++ (3.3/Xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, clang

***Problem Solved => see the update at the end***

I'm trying to use `std::function` but it looks like just include `<functional>` does not provide the definition. I have tried to compile following code:

```
#include <functional>
std::function<int(int)> f = nullptr;
```

with c++11 as compile option:

```
% clang++ -c -std=c++11 t.cc
```

cause:

```
t.cc:3:6: error: no type named 'function' in namespace 'std'
std::function<int(int)> f = nullptr;
~~~~~^
t.cc:3:14: error: expected unqualified-id
std::function<int(int)> f = nullptr;
             ^
2 errors generated.
```

what am I missing? I know C++ well but new to clang++/C++11 thus I lack of important knowledge, I guess.

I'm using clang++ on MacOS X 10.8.

**Update 1**

I have tried [a sample at cppreference.com site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) but it won't compile too. Giving some option solve the problem?

**Update 2**

Tried above sample from cppreference.com with `clang++ -c -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++11 x.cc`, and compiler still says:

```
x.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'functional' file not found
#include <functional>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Where is functional? I guess I should give `-stdlib=libc++11` or whatever but it does not work too:

```
clang: error: invalid library name in argument '-stdlib=libc++11'
```

How I can find list of argument for `-stdlib`? (note: in man page, only available options are `libc++` and `libstdc++` both of them don't work)

Or functional just does not work?

Comment: Did you compile it as C++11?

Comment: Did you pass `-std=c++11`?

Comment: As you see above command line, I'm passing -std=c++11.

Comment: @H2CO3 I might be a bit slower today than usual.

Comment: Yes I know. Tried both libc++, libstdc++, then to make sure, I tried libc++11 (as a last resort) since I can't find any list other than the man page.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have command line tools installed.  Under Xcode Preferences / Downloads, install command line tools.

Comment: I did. Without doing that, I even can't run `clang++` or such commands. I also verified the command line tools are up to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C++11, it's best to always invoke `clang` as: `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`

I use this most of the time, so I set the environment variable `$CXX` to this value. That way, I'm getting the dialect and library option in both compilation and linking. `-std=c++11` is insufficient, as clang will still use the (old) system gcc headers in `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`.

`-stdlib=libc++` will use the clang headers in `/usr/lib/c++/v1` such as `<functional>`.

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345271/xcode-4-3-and-c11-include-paths) with an answer by Howard Hinnant, who is (IIRC) an Apple engineer.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I still can't find `<functional>`. I updated the question.

Comment: @shigeya - why did you accept the answer if it did not solve the problem?

Comment: @jww becuase the answer solved the question partially. Note the "functional" part was added as part of update.

Answer (score 6):

This is not about the definition of the function. You don't have a linker error. You have a compiler error. The problem is, presumably, that the BSD/GNU/Darwin standard library installed in the real sysroot doesn't support C++11. You have to use the one that comes with Clang by specifying the `-stdlib=libc++` compiler flag.

Comment: I'm just compiling the single source code without linking (see above `-c` option above) so it does not matter wrt linking. But you may right, on the selection of standard library affect header file selection.

Comment: @shigeya I can differentiate between linkage and compilation, I assure you. That's why I said "this is not about the definition". It's about the declaration. (Well, strictly speaking, the definition may also be in the header because `std::function` is a class template, but you get my point.)

Comment: And giving `-stdlib=libc++` to the sample from cppreference.com don't help. It even can't find `functional` header file. odd. may be OSX specific issue. I will try on other platform later.

Comment: @shigeya This is an OS X-specific solution; C++11 is supported, as far as I can tell, by GNU glibc++ and g++ without any further hacking. Note that you may have to install the latest version of the development tools - check for an update in Xcode, and if available, install the most recent "Command Line Tools" package.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it ironic that Apple, the poster child company for ease-of-use, has a compilation setup that requires users to tell the compiler to use the correct C++ standard library?

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote in the updated question, `-stdlib=libc++` doesn't help in my case. Command line tools are updated. And I agree it's ironic.

Comment: @shigeya If I understand correctly, you still couldn't get this working. Now try passing `-isysroot <DEVROOT>` to the compiler, where DEVROOT is the development sysroot directory, located somewhere in /Applications/Xcode.app, and it's called `MacOSX10.8.sdk`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Still having problem. `-sysroot` doesn't help. can't find functional as same as the output on Update 2 in the above question. (Installing preview version of Xcode might help?)

Comment: Actually, Apple did a good job. Thank you very much answering quickly.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. And -1 to Apple and their ancient, non-working stuff in 2013.