# Include path not found

Tags: c, macos, gcc, eclipse-cdt, xcode5

I recently upgraded to Mavericks OS and XCode 5. Eclipse is showing me the following warning with any C projects that I'm working on:

> Invalid project path: Include path not found >(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple->darwin11/4.2.1/include).

It is unable to find the standard C libraries like stdio. Hovering over `#includes <stdio.h>` tells me 'Unresolved Inclusion: stdio.h'.

My project is able to compile in Eclipse, and via command line using gcc. Previously, before upgrading, Eclipse did not warn this.. Appreciate any assistance rendered.

Comment: Since you upgraded Xcode, it most likely means that the paths were also changed. Start looking in e.g. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/` and look until you find the correct file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.3 and C++11 include paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345271/xcode-4-3-and-c11-include-paths)

Comment: Thanks Joachim & Farouk, I've been able to resolve this on my own. It appears that upgrading Xcode removed the previously installed Command Line Tools and all the header files that came with it. I've since [installed](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) the Command Line tools for XCode 5. Everything seems to be in working order.